# JavaScript / jQuery: Problem with object in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').toggle();
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
   $('#historie .accordion_toggler .content')[i].toggle();
   $('#historie .accordion_toggler .head')[i].toggleClass('active');
}
```

Using this Code I get this error: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

My goal is to close all elements, but open the first three again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a demo, on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), showing what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is because the elements in the array are not jQuery objects so they don't have the toggle method.

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content')[i].toggle();
```

This should work:

```
$($('#historie .accordion_toggler .content')[i]).toggle();
```

but this is shorter:

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content:lt(3)').toggle();
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .head:lt(3)').toggleClass('active');
```

There is probably an easier way even if you show us a full example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be invoking the method on the DOM element(s) themselves. Try a one liner like this:

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').toggle().slice(0,3).toggle().toggleClass('active')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, just to make sure you only get elements that exist, and update the jQuery element not the native DOM element ([eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)):

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').toggle();

var go_until = $('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').length;
if($('#historie .accordion_toggler .head').length < go_until){
   go_until = $('#historie .accordion_toggler .head').length;
}

for (var i = 0; i < go_until; i++) {
   // ANOTHER CHANGE HERE, that way you get the jQuery element 
   //  and not the DOM element:
   $('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').eq(i).toggle(); 
   $('#historie .accordion_toggler .head').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only three elements, or only the first three must be toggled?

You can do this:

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').each(function(){
   $('this').toggle().toggleClass('active');
});
```

For only the first 3, you can do this

```
$('#historie .accordion_toggler .content').each(function(i){
   if(i < 3)
      $('this').toggle().toggleClass('active');
});
```